# How to Query MongoDB between two key range

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a collection called member_transaction. The sample document structure has given below:

```
{
    "memberId": "XY-123",
    "transactionsDetails": {
        "2015-07-15": [
            {
                "memberId": "1011",
                "orderId": "232",
                "topLevelcategory": "household",
                "orderValue": "34313.200"
            },
            {
                "memberId": "1011",
                "orderId": "235",
                "topLevelcategory": "Furniture",
                "orderValue": "2534.200"
            }
        ],
        "2015-07-16": [
            {
                "memberId": "1011",
                "orderId": "235",
                "topLevelcategory": "Furniture",
                "orderValue": "2534.200"
            },
            {
                "memberId": "1012",
                "orderId": "235",
                "topLevelcategory": "Grocery",
                "orderValue": "2534.200"
            },
            {
                "memberId": "1013",
                "orderId": "235",
                "topLevelcategory": "Grocery",
                "orderValue": "2534.200"
            },
            {
                "memberId": "1014",
                "orderId": "235",
                "topLevelcategory": "Grocery",
                "orderValue": "2534.200"
            }
        ],
        "2015-07-18": [
            {
                "memberId": "2011",
                "orderId": "1232",
                "topLevelcategory": "household",
                "orderValue": "34313.200"
            },
            {
                "memberId": "103",
                "orderId": "2352",
                "topLevelcategory": "Furniture",
                "orderValue": "2534.200"
            }
        ],
        "2015-07-19": [
            {
                "memberId": "311",
                "orderId": "152",
                "topLevelcategory": "household",
                "orderValue": "34313.200"
            },
            {
                "memberId": "1013",
                "orderId": "2312",
                "topLevelcategory": "Furniture",
                "orderValue": "2534.200"
            },
            {
                "memberId": "1043",
                "orderId": "2316",
                "topLevelcategory": "Grocery",
                "orderValue": "2534.200"
            },
            {
                "memberId": "1017",
                "orderId": "2315",
                "topLevelcategory": "Furniture",
                "orderValue": "2544"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How to query a mongoDB having array structure between two key, i.e. how do I extract the data between the key `"2015-07-16"` & `"2015-07-19"` from the above document ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be pretty difficult to query such a schema that has dynamic keys. A better and recommended approach is to redesign the schema in such a way that you have an embedded document that has a `date` key that holds the date value and the `transactionDetails` key that stores the array. The following demonstrates the ideal schema change:

```
db.member_transaction.insert({
    "memberId": "XY-123",
    "transactions": [
        {
            "date": ISODate("2015-07-15"),
            "transactionsDetails": [
                {
                    "memberId": "1011",
                    "orderId": "232",
                    "topLevelcategory": "household",
                    "orderValue": "34313.200"
                },
                {
                    "memberId": "1011",
                    "orderId": "235",
                    "topLevelcategory": "Furniture",
                    "orderValue": "2534.200"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": ISODate("2015-07-16"),
            "transactionsDetails": [
                {
                    "memberId": "1011",
                    "orderId": "235",
                    "topLevelcategory": "Furniture",
                    "orderValue": "2534.200"
                },
                {
                    "memberId": "1012",
                    "orderId": "235",
                    "topLevelcategory": "Grocery",
                    "orderValue": "2534.200"
                },
                {
                    "memberId": "1013",
                    "orderId": "235",
                    "topLevelcategory": "Grocery",
                    "orderValue": "2534.200"
                },
                {
                    "memberId": "1014",
                    "orderId": "235",
                    "topLevelcategory": "Grocery",
                    "orderValue": "2534.200"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": ISODate("2015-07-18"),
            "transactionsDetails": [
                {
                    "memberId": "2011",
                    "orderId": "1232",
                    "topLevelcategory": "household",
                    "orderValue": "34313.200"
                },
                {
                    "memberId": "103",
                    "orderId": "2352",
                    "topLevelcategory": "Furniture",
                    "orderValue": "2534.200"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": ISODate("2015-07-19"),
            "transactionsDetails": [
                {
                    "memberId": "311",
                    "orderId": "152",
                    "topLevelcategory": "household",
                    "orderValue": "34313.200"
                },
                {
                    "memberId": "1013",
                    "orderId": "2312",
                    "topLevelcategory": "Furniture",
                    "orderValue": "2534.200"
                },
                {
                    "memberId": "1043",
                    "orderId": "2316",
                    "topLevelcategory": "Grocery",
                    "orderValue": "2534.200"
                },
                {
                    "memberId": "1017",
                    "orderId": "2315",
                    "topLevelcategory": "Furniture",
                    "orderValue": "2544"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

With the schema above you can then use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to query your documents with that date range. The following aggregation pipeline will achieve the desired result:

```
db.member_transaction.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "transactions.date": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2015-07-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
                "$lte": ISODate("2015-07-19T00:00:00.000Z")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$transactions"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "transactions.date": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2015-07-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
                "$lte": ISODate("2015-07-19T00:00:00.000Z")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "memberId": { "$first": "$memberId" },
            "transactions": { "$push": "$transactions" }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "memberId" : "XY-123",
            "transactions" : [
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2015-07-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "transactionsDetails" : [ 
                        {
                            "memberId" : "1011",
                            "orderId" : "235",
                            "topLevelcategory" : "Furniture",
                            "orderValue" : "2534.200"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "memberId" : "1012",
                            "orderId" : "235",
                            "topLevelcategory" : "Grocery",
                            "orderValue" : "2534.200"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "memberId" : "1013",
                            "orderId" : "235",
                            "topLevelcategory" : "Grocery",
                            "orderValue" : "2534.200"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "memberId" : "1014",
                            "orderId" : "235",
                            "topLevelcategory" : "Grocery",
                            "orderValue" : "2534.200"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2015-07-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "transactionsDetails" : [ 
                        {
                            "memberId" : "2011",
                            "orderId" : "1232",
                            "topLevelcategory" : "household",
                            "orderValue" : "34313.200"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "memberId" : "103",
                            "orderId" : "2352",
                            "topLevelcategory" : "Furniture",
                            "orderValue" : "2534.200"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : ISODate("2015-07-19T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "transactionsDetails" : [ 
                        {
                            "memberId" : "311",
                            "orderId" : "152",
                            "topLevelcategory" : "household",
                            "orderValue" : "34313.200"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "memberId" : "1013",
                            "orderId" : "2312",
                            "topLevelcategory" : "Furniture",
                            "orderValue" : "2534.200"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "memberId" : "1043",
                            "orderId" : "2316",
                            "topLevelcategory" : "Grocery",
                            "orderValue" : "2534.200"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "memberId" : "1017",
                            "orderId" : "2315",
                            "topLevelcategory" : "Furniture",
                            "orderValue" : "2544"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

You could use the **[`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)** projection operator which limits the contents of an  field from the query results but not that only the **first** element matching the **[`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)** condition will be returned (i.e. the `transactionDetails` array document with date `"2015-07-16"`), thus the aggregation framework is the preferred approach as it returns all the desired result.

The following nonetheless demonstrates how the **[`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)** operator works in your example:

```
db.member_transaction.find(
    {
        "transactions.date": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2015-07-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "$lte": ISODate("2015-07-19T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    }, 
    {
        "memberId": 1,
        "transactions": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "date": {
                    "$gte": ISODate("2015-07-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "$lte": ISODate("2015-07-19T00:00:00.000Z")
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

**Sample Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55bf84307b4720b3bcd0b9ab"),
    "memberId" : "XY-123",
    "transactions" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2015-07-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "transactionsDetails" : [ 
                {
                    "memberId" : "1011",
                    "orderId" : "235",
                    "topLevelcategory" : "Furniture",
                    "orderValue" : "2534.200"
                }, 
                {
                    "memberId" : "1012",
                    "orderId" : "235",
                    "topLevelcategory" : "Grocery",
                    "orderValue" : "2534.200"
                }, 
                {
                    "memberId" : "1013",
                    "orderId" : "235",
                    "topLevelcategory" : "Grocery",
                    "orderValue" : "2534.200"
                }, 
                {
                    "memberId" : "1014",
                    "orderId" : "235",
                    "topLevelcategory" : "Grocery",
                    "orderValue" : "2534.200"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Chridam, Without using aggregation can we extract the data between date range in your structure??

Comment: @SanjayakumarSahu It's possible through the [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator which limits the contents of an <array> field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) condition.

Comment: Could you please share a sample query & its output using $elemMatch in the above structure ?

Comment: @SanjayakumarSahu I've updated the answer to include the **`$elemMatch`** operator and its limitation.